# ¿Como agregar un else a una sentencia de mas de un IF?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Tengo un problema en mi proyecto, quisiera saber como agregar una sentencia de else a un "grupo" de If que tengo en mi proyecto, cuando agrego el else del grupo de if me dice que el else tiene problemas ya que no encuentra el if.
Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias de antemano.

```
class Manejador implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String pal;

        if(bcc.isEnabled()) {
            pal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Porfavor, digite el grupo que desea consultar:");
            {
                if(pal.matches("Grupo A"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Rusia\n Arabia Saudi\n Egipto\n Uruguay");

                if(pal.matches("Grupo B"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Portugal\n España\n Marruecos\n Irán");

                if(pal.matches("Grupo C"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Francia\n Australia\n Peru\n Dinamarca");

                if(pal.matches("Grupo D"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Argentina\n Islandia\n Croacia\n Nigeria");

                if(pal.matches("Grupo E"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Brasil\n Suiza\n Costa Rica\n Serbia");

                if(pal.matches("Grupo F"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Alemania\n Mexico\n Suecia\n Corea del Sur");

                if(pal.matches("Grupo G"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Bélgica\n Panamá\n Túnez\n Inglaterra");

                if(pal.matches("Grupo H"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Polonia\n Japon\n Colombia\n Senegal");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: por que usas la etiqueta de javascript? si es lenguaje java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece que lo que tienes es un error de concepto. Para cada condicional `if` solo puedes tener un `else` o `else if` asociado. Por ejemplo, si tienes este código:

```
if (num1 == num2)
    System.out.println("Los números son iguales");
if (num1 > num2)
    System.out.println("El número 1 es mayor");
else
    System.out.println("El número 2 es mayor");
```

Van a ocurrir 2 cosas:
1 - Siempre se van a comprobar ambos `if`, porque son independientes entre si.
2 - El `else` se corresponde solo al segundo `if`, por lo que siempre que se no cumpla que `num1 > num`, el programa entrará en el `else` y por se imprimirá `El número 2 es mayor`. Esto ocurrirá aunque los número sean iguales, ya que el primer `if` no tiene nada que ver con el segundo.

Para evitar el comportamiento anterior solo debe utilizar un `else if`, y así se garantiza que cuando se cumpla cualquiera de las condiciones, el programa no siga comprobando las siguientes. Ejemplo:

```
if (num1 == num2)
    System.out.println("Los números son iguales");
else if (num1 > num2)
    System.out.println("El número 1 es mayor");
else
    System.out.println("El número 2 es mayor");
```

Ahora si que se imprime el texto `El número 2 es mayor` solo cuando ambos `if` no se cumplan.

En tu caso como sería:

```
        if(bcc.isEnabled()) {
            pal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Porfavor, digite el grupo que desea consultar:");

            if(pal.matches("Grupo A"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Rusia\n Arabia Saudi\n Egipto\n Uruguay");
            else if(pal.matches("Grupo B"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Portugal\n España\n Marruecos\n Irán");
            else if(pal.matches("Grupo C"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Francia\n Australia\n Peru\n Dinamarca");
            else if(pal.matches("Grupo D"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Argentina\n Islandia\n Croacia\n Nigeria");
            else if(pal.matches("Grupo E"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Brasil\n Suiza\n Costa Rica\n Serbia");
            else if(pal.matches("Grupo F"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Alemania\n Mexico\n Suecia\n Corea del Sur");
            else if(pal.matches("Grupo G"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Bélgica\n Panamá\n Túnez\n Inglaterra");
            else if(pal.matches("Grupo H"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Polonia\n Japon\n Colombia\n Senegal");
            else
                System.out.println();
        }
```

Es importante recordar que las llaves solo son necesarias si dentro del `if` o del `else` necesitas tener varias lineas de código, en caso contrario son totalmente opcionales utilizarlas o no.

Comment: Muchisisisisisisimaaaaaaas gracias. Me fue de muchisima ayuda, para ser especifico ese era el error que tenia, ya pude solucionarlo, muchisimas gracais.

Comment: @DiegoAlejandro Recuerda marcar la respuesta que te ha servido como respuesta correcta, tienes algunas preguntas hechas en la comunidad con respuestas que te han servido pero no has marcado ninguna de ellas.

Comment: Opcionales si, aunque por buenas prácticas se recomienda siempre usar las llaves

Answer (score 4):

Lo que tienes ahí son if individuales que hacen parte de un bloque de código entre `{ }`, cualquier `else` que agregues hará parte del if inmediatamente superior, si lo agregas al final será parte del último `if`

```
if(pal.matches("Grupo H")){ ... } else { /* aca*/}
```

Dado que pal no puede tener varios valores al mismo tiempo, es decir

`pal.matches("Grupo A")` y `pal.matches("Grupo B")` no pueden ser true al mismo tiempo. Lo que necesitas hacer es re-escrbir tus condicionales

```
if(pal.matches("Grupo A")){ ... }
else if(pal.matches("Grupo B")) { ... }
...
else {
/** tus condiciones si no se cumplen ninguna de las anteriores**/
}
```

Podrías refactorizar tu código para que use un [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) y reducir la cantidad de `if`s, por ejemplo:

```
Map<String,String> mapa = new HashMap<String,String>();
mapa.put("Grupo a", "Mensaje a...");
mapa.put("Grupo b", "Mensaje b...");
//rellenar el resto de grupos
if(mapa.containsKey(pal)){
//mostrar mensaje
}
else {
//ejecutar si no  se especificó ningún grupo
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, me fue de muchisima ayuda aunque lo solucione con la respuesta de E.Betanzos, pero de igual manera, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Usar un `HashMap` me parece la mejor solución, sólo que, según el código del OP, no se busca un valor exacto, pues usa `matches`, por lo tanto, `containsKey` sólo funcionará cuando el valor sea **exactamente** `Grupo A`, `Grupo B`... etc. Otra opción que prefiero en estos casos es usar `switch` en vez de tantos `if ... else if...`

Comment: En este caso la expresión regular del matches es una cadena simple sin meta carácteres por lo que el matches y containsKey son equivalentes.

Answer (score 0):

¿Ya intentaste poner llaves al inicio y término de cada if?
Sé que sin ponerlas debería funcionar pero llegué a tener ese tipo de problemasy con unas llaves se solucionaba
También puedes tratar con:

```
else if(condicion){
printf("Hola");
}else if(condicion){
printf("Adios");
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: por favor edita tu respuesta en la parte del código para hacerla entendible, con las herramientas del editor de código

Comment: Las llaves no son el problema. Si solo tienes una sentencia dentro del `if` no necesitas llaves.

Comment: No me funciono, acabo de probar y no me funciona, necesito saber como agregarle la sentencia de salida en el else a ese grupo de if urgentemente :(

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que solo se aplica uno de los `if`, en tal caso esto debería funcionar:

```
class Manejador implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String pal;

        if(bcc.isEnabled()) {
            pal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Porfavor, digite el grupo que desea consultar:");
            {
                if(pal.matches("Grupo A"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Rusia\n Arabia Saudi\n Egipto\n Uruguay");
                //A partir del segundo, else if en vez de solo if
                else if(pal.matches("Grupo B"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Portugal\n España\n Marruecos\n Irán");

                else if(pal.matches("Grupo C"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Francia\n Australia\n Peru\n Dinamarca");

                else if(pal.matches("Grupo D"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Argentina\n Islandia\n Croacia\n Nigeria");

                else if(pal.matches("Grupo E"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Brasil\n Suiza\n Costa Rica\n Serbia");

                else if(pal.matches("Grupo F"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Alemania\n Mexico\n Suecia\n Corea del Sur");

                else if(pal.matches("Grupo G"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Bélgica\n Panamá\n Túnez\n Inglaterra");

                else if(pal.matches("Grupo H"))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pal+"\n Polonia\n Japon\n Colombia\n Senegal");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

En Java no existe tal cosa como aplicar un `else` en caso de que no se ejecute ningún `if` de un grupo. Una forma de conseguir ese efecto es con [switch-case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) mediante la etiqueta `default`. En caso de no poder usar esto, puedes añadir a cada uno de los condicionales una variable que cambia si entras en uno de estos, y al final un último condicional que chequea si no se ha activado:

```
boolean activado = false;
if(condicion1){
    //...
    activado = true;
}
if(condicion2){
    //...
    activado = true;
}
if(condicion3){
    //...
    activado = true;
}
//Revisamos:
if(activado == false){//No entró en ninguno
    //...
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, me fue de muchisima ayuda aunque lo solucione con la respuesta de E.Betanzos, pero de igual manera, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda